# Reading data in a loop error - "must be str, not numpy.int32"

Tags: python, list, loops, int

Python 3

I need to plot a time series of Ozone from August 3rd to August 10th using this data website . I need to "stitch" the data together.

http://skywatch.colorado.edu/data/ozone_18_09_03.dat
So right now I have

```
pre= 'http://skywatch.colorado.edu/data/ozone_18_09_0'

ozone = []
utc = []
dates = np.arange(3,10,1)


for date in dates: 
    url = pre + dates[i] + ".dat"
    lines = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()
    for line in lines: #for x number of times (however many lines appear in the dataset)
        entries = line.decode("utf-8").split("\t")
        if entries[0][0] != ';': #if there are entries that do not have a semicolon 
            utc.append(float(entries[0][0:2]) + \
                   float(entries[0][3:5])/60. + \
                   float(entries[0][6:8])/3600.)
        #converts the UTC time variable into a float and adds it to the list 'utc'
            ozone.append(float(entries[1]))
```

When I try to run this I get an error

----> 9     url = pre + dates[i] + ".dat"

TypeError: must be str, not numpy.int32
note sure How to deal with this

Comment: Seems like you have to convert `dates[i]` to string before concatenating into `url`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to explicitly convert the numpy.int32 objects to strings, as numpy most likely did not define `__add__(self, other)` for `other: str`.

Also, you're iterating through `dates` with the variable `date`, so you would use something like this:

```
url = pre + str(date) + ".dat"
```